# How to unit-test a SignalR 1.1.3 Hub

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I'm seeing several examples of how to unit-test a SignalR Hub on stackoverflow ([Unittest SignalR Hubs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797368/unittest-signalr-hubs)) and around the internet.

However, they are all based on pre-1.1.3 versions and the involved code breaks when using it with SignalR 1.1.3.

I've checked the source code of SignalR and some SignalR-based projects, specifically the tests, but cannot find anything useful to work with.

Would appreciate some help on how to do this.

Thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unittest SignalR Hubs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797368/unittest-signalr-hubs)

Comment: As from SignalR 2.0, unit-testing a Hub is easy and straight-forward. See
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/troubleshooting-and-debugging/unit-testing-signalr-applications